# How to change value field in html input tag using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input

The following html tag:

```
<input id="input-value" title="Search" type="text" value="">
```

I want to change the value attribute from "" to "foo".

```
<input id="input-value" title="Search" type="text" value="foo">
```

I am trying this with `send_keys()` with no success.

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_id("input-value")
ele.send_keys("foo")
ele.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Changing the contents of an input via the UI doesn't change the underlying `value` attribute.

Comment: Yes, figured that out. Thanks @DebanjanB.
I am trying to change the contents of a search input tag. The website(web.whatsapp) is using react.js. I am trying to search by name using the field.

Answer (score 5):

To edit the `value` attribute and assign the value **`foo`** to it you can use the following code block which uses the JavascriptExecutor :

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input#input-value")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','foo')", ele)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .click() before .send_keys() like:

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_id("input-value")
ele.click()
ele.send_keys("foo")
ele.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```