# How to change the transform property with selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes, setattribute

I am trying to change the transform property on this particular website: https://www.weltsparen.de/etf-portfolio/WI04

I'm trying to set the first translate parameter to 0 instead of 275 with the selenium WebDriver and then probably run the website again, because I want to get another values from the graph showed in the figure bellow, and this parameters in the translate are the positions of the values.

Graph:

[image: Graph]

HTML:

```
<g class="Indicatorstyles__indicator--3lFtS" display="block" transform="translate(275,370)">
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily **set** the first translate parameter to `0` instead of `275` using [setAttribute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690) at the client-side using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491). However this change won't be updated to the server-side.

Hence, when you would run the website again i.e. `refresh()` or invoke `get()` the changes would be lost.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Change value field in html input tag using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634093/change-value-field-in-html-input-tag-using-selenium-in-python/47634326#47634326)
- [How to send a date directly as text to a calendar control with readonly attribute using Selenium through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449375/how-to-send-a-date-directly-as-text-to-a-calendar-control-with-readonly-attribut/57453876#57453876)