# How to change the value of the class attribute of an element using Python and Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, setattribute

I want to change the class name, but it doesn't work for me.

```
<div class="vcp-controls-panel vcp-playing hide">
```

FullXpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[4]
```

I want to change `vcp-playing hide` to `vcp-playing show` but it doesn't work

```
selects = driver.find_element_by_class_name("vcp-playing hide")
    for select in selects:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'vcp-playing show')", select)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the existing element already have the *classname* attribute set:

```
<div class="vcp-controls-panel vcp-playing hide">
```

You can remove the existing attributes through [`removeAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453876/7429447) set the new attributes using [`setAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634326/7429447) as follows:

```
selects = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vcp-controls-panel.vcp-playing.hide")
for select in selects:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class')", select);
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','vcp-controls-panel vcp-playing show')", select)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

how about do it completely in javascript

```py
driver.execute_script("""
    selects = document.querySelectorAll('.vcp-playing.hide')
    selects.forEach(e => e.setAttribute('class', 'vcp-playing show'))
""")
```

Comment: No errors occur, but nothing changes.

Comment: @jesusay is it possible to try Javascript part in directly in Brower console... and see what's happened

Comment: >`selects = document.querySelectorAll('.vcp-playing.hide')`
`NodeList [div.vcp-controls-panel.vcp-playing.hide]0: div.vcp-controls-panel.vcp-playing.hidelength: 1[[Prototype]]: NodeList`

`181570b651df4cd8c51d.js?max_age=31536000:1 predict: 226.85693359375 ms`

>`selects.forEach(e => e.setAttribute('class', 'vcp-playing show')`
`VM26872:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`