# Python Selenium How to click on the Input type number increment or decrement buttons

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

With Python Selenium how can I click on the increment or decrement buttons of an Input type number. The increment and decrement buttons are Browser specific objects and not part of the DOM. So I can not use the inspector to get the xpath.
I want to increment and decrement these inputs.

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="qty" value="69">
```

Edge:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Since they do not appear in the DOM inspector (for either browser) I don't see how to make the click action for those buttons:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input[1]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the existing attribute through `removeAttribute()` set back the new attribute using [`setAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634326/7429447) as follows:

```
counter = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='qty'][type='number']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('value')", counter);
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','50')", counter)
```

In a single line:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','50')", driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='qty'][type='number']"))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Is it not possible to click on the increment and or decrement buttons? (with Selenium)

Comment: I think the increment and or decrement buttons are **not** buttons as such but integral part of a control. However, the key to all the questions/assumptions may be found in it's parent/ancestor elements.