# Field not clearing Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

Any ideas on how to get the field to clear the pre-filled text prior to setting new text - I have attempted the previously recommended solutions and this is what I currently have - this merely just appends to the current pre-filled text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#Install Chrome Extension
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#implicit wait
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
#maximize browser
driver.maximize_window()
#launch URL
driver.get("https://www.futbin.com/fut-card-creator/22")

#Set Vars
rating = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "rating_change")))
rating.click()
rating.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
rating.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
rating.send_keys("90")

driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

position = driver.find_element(By.ID, "position_change")
position.click()
position.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
position.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
position.send_keys("ST")
```

Comment: I woke up this morning and it is suddenly working... I am not sure why it wasn't working yesterday but it is functioning fine this morning

Answer (score 1):

This is how you clear an input field in selenium (based on your existing code):

```
[...]
rating = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "rating_change")))
rating.click()
rating.clear() ## field will be cleared and you can input your value
[...]
```

Comment: I can confirm this does work aswell, when I tested this last night it wasn't functioning so went the CTRL A DEL route but yes this does work and is shorter!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired value within the desired element using [`setAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634326/7429447) method as follows:

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.futbin.com/fut-card-creator/22'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='dismiss cookie message']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','96')", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#rating_change"))))
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: 96]

Comment: Nopes :) correct place. OP asked _"how to get the field to clear the pre-filled text"_, user input is accomodated within `value` attribute, so you can set it directly.

Comment: This does indeed replace the pre-filled out value, however, does not trigger the change on the card face on the left - need to trigger the send_keys in order to get it to trigger the card change

Comment: Never mind, you seem to get a working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102327/field-not-clearing-selenium-python/73102391#comment129115622_73102391) ;)