# Select Date from dropdown datepicker using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, setattribute, readonly-attribute

I tried to select different date rather than default (current date). e.g the initial page pop up with shareholding date : 2023/02/01, but I want to select different date say, 2022/12/23 from the dropdown menu.

My environment is : Selenium 4.3.0 and Python 3.9.7, Chrome

Following is my code:

```
url = "https://www3.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk&t=hk&t=hk&t=hk"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
select_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='txtShareholdingDate']").click()
# The above pop up the required page with Date dropdown, tried different code to select the date but failed. My codes are:

action = ActionChains(select_element)
action.send_keys("2023",Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
action.send_keys("1",Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
action.send_keys("31",Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
action.perform()
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

# Also tried
select = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtShareholdingDate")
select.select_by_value("2023/01/31")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnSearch').click()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For the error - "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'" - you have to modify the line like - select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtShareholdingDate")) , and add the import - from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input>` element to select a date within the [website](https://www3.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk&t=hk&t=hk&t=hk) is having the attribute *`readonly="readonly"`* set:

```
<input name="txtShareholdingDate" type="text" value="2023/02/01" id="txtShareholdingDate" class="input-searchDate active" data-reset="2023/02/01" readonly="readonly">
```

---

### Solution

To select a date you need to [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577612/7429447) the *`readonly`* attribute and [set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634326/7429447) the *`value`* attribute to the new ***date*** as follows:

```
driver.get("https://www3.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket.aspx?t=hk&t=hk&t=hk&t=hk")
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtShareholdingDate")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '2023/01/31')", element)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#btnSearch").click()
```

Browser snapshot:

[image: date_select]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript to set the dat without having to set the date by using ActionChains as you have. This is also much quicker and less error prone

```
newDate = "2023/01/18"
dateElement = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='txtShareholdingDate']")))
print(dateElement .get_attribute("value"))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])", dateElement , newDate )
```

Comment: Why do you need _`time.sleep(5)`_ at the fag end of your code?

Comment: Must be a copy paste issue from my ide. Updated

Comment: Indented your code and removed the blank lines. Let me know if you disagree, then I will revert back the changes.

Answer (score 0):

`select` tag is not used in the HTML DOM for this dropdown. Hence select class cannot be used in this case.

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='txtShareholdingDate']").click()`

After the above line, just try the following code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-value='2022']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-value='11']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-value='23']").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnSearch").click()
```

Above 4 lines will click on dropdown values 2022, 11, 23 and then clicks on Search button

Comment: Thanks Shawn, it works except interesting that "11" gives "12" instead ,  I also tried out other value "10" , it gives me "11" . Looks like the month value will have the month result  +1.